# Can not correctly format the dataframe column in a datetime using pd.to datetime()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime, strftime

I have the DataFrame `df` with columns `date` and `number`. Those columns has dtype `object`. I want to format column `df[date]` to `datetime64[ns]` and this column should look exactly the same. I am read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and chose expression for format based on it (hope this expression looks fine).
My `df` looks like this:

```
        date number
0  Tue 14-08      3
1  Wed 15-08      5
2  Thu 16-08     10
3  Fri 17-08     18
4  Sat 18-08     22
```

Next I doing that:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format = "%a %d-%m")
```

And `df["date"]` is `datetime64[ns]` but column is changed:

```
        date number
0 1900-08-14      3
1 1900-08-15      5
2 1900-08-16     10
3 1900-08-17     18
4 1900-08-18     22
```

I also have used this (but having the same result as above):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%a %d-%m'))
```

and this(`df["date"]` looking as what i want but dtype is `object` and not `datetime64[ns]`):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.\
                              strptime(x,'%a %d-%m').strftime("%a %d-%m"))
```

Code to reproduce:

```
#import all what we need
import pandas as pd
import datetime
#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["Tue 14-08",
                           "Wed 15-08",
                           "Thu 16-08",
                           "Fri 17-08",
                           "Sat 18-08"],
                   "number":["3","5","10","18","22"]})
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
#Convert df["date"] column in datetime64[ns]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format = "%a %d-%m")
#df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%a %d-%m'))
#df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.\
#                              strptime(x,'%a %d-%m').strftime("%a %d-%m"))
#Check df
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

Comment: There is no year info in your datetime string; how else can this be achieved? By default, the year selected will be 1900, same as with the regular python `datetime` library. This at least facilitates computations when you try to subtract datetimes. What year are you expecting?

Comment: I'm confused at your edit. _Why_ should the column look exactly the same? You're not converting to `datetime64[ns]` for the fun of it, you're doing it presumably for calculations. If you want to represent the column as-is, you will have to use `dt.strftime` to get back to a string format once you've done whatever calculations you need to do.

Comment: @roganjosh that or create a new datetime column instead of overwriting the original...

Comment: @JonClements yep, or even a temporary series to do whatever calculation they need to do